# Populate router with external json

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I would like to add routes from an external json file, which can change at runtime, to my Nuxt application. A similar topic can be found [here](https://github.com/nuxt-community/router-module/issues/4#issuecomment-333312347).

I've overridden the default Nuxt router with my own implementation. If I import the routes async using axios + `router.addRoutes()`, I seem to loose the server side rendering. It seems like `createRouter` will have async support, but it's not in an official release of Nuxt yet.

How do I import a js/json file *synchronously* to my `router.js` below, so that I can populate the routes? I want to be able to configure the routes at runtime, so I don't want it to be a part of the bundle.

**modules/router.js:**

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = function () {
  this.nuxt.options.build.createRoutes = () => {}
  this.addTemplate({
    fileName: 'router.js',
    src: path.resolve(`${this.options.srcDir}`, 'router.js')
  })
}
```

**nuxt.config.js:**

```
modules: ['~/modules/router']
```

**router.js:**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(Router)

export function createRouter () {
  const router = new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    routes: [/* ... */]
  })

  return router
}
```

Comment: i think you could  import your json file like `import myroutes from 'thepath/routes.json'` and `... mode:'hidtory',routes:myroutes...`

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim If I do that, it will be part of the bundle when I build.

Comment: yes i understood, did you try use axios to accomplish that?

Comment: @boussadjrabrahim Yeah I've tried the async method as I mentioned but the load needs to execute synchronously at the moment

Comment: Did you consider to use a NPM package like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request)?

Comment: @P3trur0 Not sure how I missed that, feel free to post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with `sync-request`.

It is a NPM package aimed to perform synchronous web requests. It is available [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sync-request).

Please note that, as stated in the documentation of the package itself, it is not suitable for production environment, probably because of application hanging in case of missing data.

Answer (score 0):

So `await` would be an answer but I guess you already tried that? So, something like this.

```
const routeFile = await fetch('pathToTheJsonFile');
const routes = await routeFile.json();
```

In case you can't make the method async, as a workaround maybe use jQuery. I don't like this but if there's no other option, for now, use `async: false` in jQuery get.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'pathToYourJsonRoutes',
    success: function (result) {

    },
    async: false
});
```

Comment: "So await would be an answer" - no, I want to load data synchronously, as mentioned.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but if you don't want the code execution to continue until the promise is resolved, this will solve that issue. Routes should be loaded. If you want it sync, then unfortunately at least for the moment you'll need jquery. With axios I think it is not possible currently.